# How to determine what program send the packet recorded in Wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I was taking some tutorials on Wireshark in order to analyze the packets sent and received when talking to a web server for purposes of learning.

When I start listening/recording packets in Wireshark, there where so many packages being recorded (700 packages per minute). Is it normal to have that much traffic if I have all the programs that will cause traffic such as all browsers, log me in, dropbox, goto meeting, etc., closed?

In order to try to solve the problem I am analyzing random packets. Take for instance this filter:

[image]

I just selected a random IP: `74.125.130.99`.

**So how can I know from what program those packets where created?** Also how can I get more info about that communication bwtween my computer (192.168.0.139) and that server (74.125.130.99)?

I just selected a random IP from the Wireshark capture. There are also other IPs that I have no idea why they are communicating with my computer. How can I figure that out?

Comment: If you do a whois on that IP address, it shows that it's owned by Google.

Comment: The command `netstat -b -a` on cmd is very helpful too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process id doesn't make it onto the stream that Wireshark is reading.
[Netmon](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) is better suited for this task on Windows.